# How do i recognize 2 digits as separated digits?

Tags: java

So basically the assignment says i need to get a number 'n' from the user and for all the numbers between 1 to 'n' code the program to print all the numbers *divided by 3 without residue* && *print ONLY the numbers that both (or one) of their digits equal to 5 or less*, for example if the user give 22 the programs prints `3,12,21`.

thats what ive done by now (the place i putted a question mark is where im having hard time to figure out what to do) so this code in not compiled yet :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    System.out.println("Enter A Random Number: ");
    num = get.nextInt();
    for (int i=1;i>0 && i<=num;i++) {
        if (i%3==0 && ?)
        System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Does the code shared by you compile even?

Comment: All digit <=5 or just one ? this is not the same^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about the second part of your question but based on the first part and what I got from the second part ( that the sum of the digits of numbers that is equal or less to 5 should only be printed )
Here is the code for your program : (It should work perfectly, update me if you find any problems)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    System.out.println("User please enter a number of your choice : ");
    num = get.nextInt();

    for(int x = 1 ; x < num ; x++){
    String number = ""+ x ;
    int sum = 0 ;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < number.length() ; i ++ ){
         sum +=number.charAt(i)-'0' ; }

    if(x % 3 == 0 && sum <= 5){
       System.out.println(x) ; }

    sum = 0 ; 
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do. So, you have to go through every digit so, I converted it into a string and then matched the regex for 1 to 5 on that character and then put it back in another string and it solves it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
int num;
System.out.println("Enter A Random Number: ");
num =Integer.parseInt(get.nextLine());
for(int i =1;i<=num; i++){

    if(i%3==0){
        String input = Integer.toString(i);
        String toPrint = "";
        for(int j =0 ; j<input.length();j++){
            if(Character.toString(input.charAt(j)).matches("^[1-5]$")){
                toPrint+=Character.toString(input.charAt(j));
            }
        }
               //check the length to avoid cases like 30,60 etc.
                if(input.length()==toPrint.length()){
                System.out.println(toPrint);
        }

    }  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> divided by 3 without residue

If you understand what "without residue" means, then I assume you are familiar with modulo arithmetic. In programming, we have the modulo operator `%` which returns the remainder from a division. So `25 % 8` evaluates to `1`. You can use this to get the digits of a number `21 % 10` evalutes to `1` which is exactly the ones digit. To get the the tens digit, we need to divide by 10 first `21 / 10 % 10` evaluates to 2. This works because integer division throws away the remainder.